# Tools for Window service performance testing

Tags: c#, performance, windows-services

Can you recommend open source and commercial tools for testing Windows services?  I want to test for memory usage, leaks, etc.

C# 2.0 - Window Services.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any performance testing tools for .NET with a windows service.

You can start by using the built in performance monitor to see memory usage over time and other metrics - this will let you measure performance characteristics and see if your service is leaking memory etc.

If you want to go further, [ANTS Performance Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/index.htm) by redgate is very good, as is [dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/index.html) by jet brains.

[Here](http://csharp-source.net/open-source/profilers) is a list of open source .NET profilers.